# Rust with sqlx::postgres and i64

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I'm new to Rust, and trying to implement an API using sqlx and PostgresQL.
When reading about PostgresQL, it seems like it doesn't support `u64`, as MySQL does. So I have changed my code to `i64`, as [documented here](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.4.2/sqlx/struct.Postgres.html?search=).

However it seems like some of my code still expects a `u64` value:

An example of the code:

```
pub async fn drop_table(&self) -> Result<i64, sqlx::Error> {
    sqlx::query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;")
        .execute(&*self.pool)
        .await
}
```

And the error it produces:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\dao\user_dao.rs:7:9
  |
7 | /         sqlx::query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;")
8 | |             .execute(&*self.pool)
9 | |             .await
  | |__________________^ expected `i64`, found `u64`
  |
  = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<i64, _>`
             found enum `std::result::Result<u64, _>`
```

I could probably cast the variable, but that could end up in a panic at runtime, so what would be the proper way to handle it?

I've used [this](https://github.com/jamesjmeyer210/actix_sqlx_mysql_user_crud) as a reference application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [reference application is using sqlx v0.3.5](https://github.com/jamesjmeyer210/actix_sqlx_mysql_user_crud/blob/main/Cargo.toml#L16) and in that version of `sqlx` the [`execute`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.5/sqlx/struct.Query.html#method.execute) method always returns a `Result<u64, sqlx::Error>` regardless of whether you're executing the query on a PostgresQL connection or a MySQL connection. The `u64` represents the number of rows affected by executing the query and will always be unsigned. You should update the signature of `drop_table` to reflect that:

```rust
pub async fn drop_table(&self) -> Result<u64, sqlx::Error> {
    sqlx::query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;")
        .execute(&*self.pool)
        .await
}
```